# I want to put an imgae + h5 inside the "a" tag in WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, image

I want to put an image + h5 inside the "a" tage in WordPress..it seem's not working..  properly syntax error whith calling the image!..

```
echo '<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">' . "<img src='".get_post_meta($post->ID, "news_images", true) . "' />"  .$recent["post_title"].'</a> </li> ';
```

Comment: please edit your question. it is not clear.

Comment: Soory Mr.kakkar..it's my first time..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<li><a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '"><img     src='".get_post_meta($post->ID, "news_images", true) . "' />  .$recent["post_title"]</a> </li>
```

Hope this works